# CasperJS : read web page from page that loads after for submission

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

My objective is to read data from posted page ( page that loads after form submission ) using casperJS.

Explanation :
I have script in casperJS that reads a webpage http://www.example.com/details and logs in console.
I dont have problem reading from this initial page.
Now there is a href link which upon clicking it submits form to the same url ( form action self ) http://www.example.com/details and updates newly fetched data in one of dom element.

I want to read the newly fetched data after the page loads after form submission.

Here is the part of the script that does this process.

```
casper.start('http://www.example.com/details', function () {
this.page.injectJs('/path../to../jquery.min.js');
casper.evaluate(function () {
    var all_data = $('.selector').text();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(all_data));
});

// submitting hidden form by clicking href
$('.formSubmit').click();
casper.then(function(){
    casper.wait(5000, function(){
        casper.evaluate(function () {
            var new_data = $('.selector').text();
            console.log(JSON.stringify(new_data));
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it isn't submitting the form at all, try:

`casper.then(function(){
    this.mouseEvent('click','.formSubmit');
});`

instead of `$('.formSubmit').click();`